# How to debug a shell script invoked with "exec"?

Tags: bash, shell, debugging

Suppose I've got a bash script `foo.bash`, which uses `exec` to run another bash script:

```
exec bar.bash
```

Now am debugging both `foo.bash` and `bar.bash`. I am running `foo.bash` with `bash -x` but it does not run `bar.bash` in debug mode. What should I do to run `bar.bash` in debug mode too ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also export [`SHELLOPTS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html) from `foo.bash` as well to export the shell options.

```
export SHELLOPTS
```

Comment: Can I do it without modifying `foo.bash` ?

Comment: You can set in `-x` from the calling shell: `$ set -x; export SHELLOPTS; ./foo.bash` - this wouldn't require changes to `foo.bash`. You can also run this from a subshell so that debug output is *not* printed for everything else: `$ (set -x; export SHELLOPTS; ./foo.bash)`.

Answer (score 1):

Add `-x` to `bar.bash`'s shebang line:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
```

If you don't want to modify `bar.bash`, change the `exec` line to:

```
exec bash -x bar.bash
```